# Nautilus(and Nemo too) cannot Mount if mount option is noauto/user and the mount point has non-western character

Tags: mount, nautilus, fstab

I reporot this a bug on launchpad, but I'm not sure it is a bug..
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1428417

On Ubuntu 14.04(64bit), I configured /etc/fstab something like this.

```
server:/Video   /media/Video-Nfs nfs    auto 0 0
server:/강좌  /media/강좌-Nfs   nfs auto 0 0
```

It works fine.

I changed and added options, noauto, user.

```
server:/Video   /media/Video-Nfs nfs    noauto,user 0 0
server:/강좌  /media/강좌-Nfs   nfs noauto,user 0 0
```

After that, I can mount `/media/Video-Nfs` by clicking the icon on the Nautilus's Network panel. It works.
However, when I click `강좌-Nfs` icon on the Nautilus, I got this message.

```
 mount: can't find /media/\352\260\225\354\242\214-Nfs in /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab
```

I tried to mount that directory with mount command, like this.

```
$ mount /media/강좌-Nfs/
```

It works. also `umount /media/강좌-Nfs/` works.

I think Nautilus (and Nemo) cannot handle non-western characters when it is related with mount options.
I'm not sure this is a bug or there might be a solution or a workaround.

Comment: Please don't file bugs on Launchpad if the project isn't managed by Canonical. I did that the first time ever filing a bug and it resulted in the maintainers of that program or library to not actually notice the bug report until months later. Instead, try to find out how to report bugs for the specific project. In the case of nautilus, searching for "gnome nautilus" in most search engines should get you [here](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Apps/Nautilus) somehow. On the bottom of that page, you'll find a link for creating a bug report in GNOMEs Bugzilla. Search for existing bugs first!

Answer (score 0):

If you want a workaround, I would suggest using ASCII characters for the mount point:

```
server:/강좌  /media/foo-Nfs   nfs noauto,user 0 0
```